# notepad++ convert \section{text} to # text

Tags: regex, markdown, notepad++

I have some **tex** files with  `\section{text}` and `\subsection{text}`, etc. And I want to convert them to `# text` and `## text` in **markdown** files using regular expressions in  **Notepad++**. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the replace window with Ctrl + H. Check the radio button "Regular Expression" and search for:

```
\\section\{([^}]*)}
```

And replace with:

```
# \1
```

For subsections:

```
\\subsection\{([^}]*)}
## \1
```

What we're doing:

- `\\` is an escaped backslash matching the litteral backslash of your expression
- `{` needs to be escaped as well otherwise it would be recognized as quantifier, hence `\{`
- `([^}]*)` is a group made of 0 or more characters that are NOT `}`
- `\1` is a reference to the first and only group of our regular expression

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in a single pass:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\\(sub)?section{([^}]*)}`
- Replace with: `(?1#)# $2`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\\          # a backslash, have to be escaped
(sub)?      # group 1, literally "sub", optional
section{    # literally
([^}]*)     # group 2, 0 or more any character that is not "}"
}           # "}" character
```

**Replacement:**

```
(?1#)       # conditional replace, if group 1 exists, print a "#"
# $2        # "#", a space and content of group 2
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]